# How to play podcast files in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, podcast

I am working on app which contains radio and podcast. Where I am able to play live streaming radio. Also I am getting list of podcast from iTunes but don't found streaming link for songs in response. Response gives link to collection of audio files. So how to get link to actual path to sound file?

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=song&country=IN&media=podcast&entity=podcast

```
   import AFNetworking

     class PodcastApi {

        fileprivate let baseUrl = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/")
        /// Shared singletone object of WSApi
        static let shared : PodcastApi = {
            let instance = PodcastApi()
            return instance
        }()


        private func showNetworkActivity(){
            // Turn on network indicator in status bar
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        }

        private func hideNetworkActivity(){
            // Turn off network indicator in status bar
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }

        private func getPath(term:String)->String{
            return "search?term=\(term)&country=IN&media=podcast&entity=podcast"
        }

        func getPodcasts(term:String,completionHandler:@escaping (_ status:Bool, _ responseObject:Any)->()){

            if !ReachabilityManager.shared.isReachable {
                let error = WSError()
                error.errorTitle = "Network error"
                error.errorDescription = "Unable to connect, please check your internet connectivity."
                completionHandler(false,error)
                return
            }

            self.showNetworkActivity()
            let sessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager(baseURL: baseUrl, sessionConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
            sessionManager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
            sessionManager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
            let urlPath =  getPath(term: term)

            sessionManager.get(urlPath, parameters: nil, progress: { progress in

            }, success: { task, responseObject in

                self.hideNetworkActivity()
                var podcasts = [Podcast]()
                if let disc = responseObject as? [String:Any]{
                    podcasts.append(contentsOf: Podcast.GetPodcasts(disc: disc))
                }
                completionHandler(true,podcasts)

            }, failure: { operation, err in
                self.hideNetworkActivity()
                let error = WSError(error: err as NSError)
                completionHandler(false,error)

            })

        }

}

 Response is

{
      "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "podcast",
      "collectionId": 415636728,
      "trackId": 415636728,
      "artistName": "Kurt Nichols",
      "collectionName": "New Song Fellowship",
      "trackName": "New Song Fellowship",
      "collectionCensoredName": "New Song Fellowship",
      "trackCensoredName": "New Song Fellowship",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/in/podcast/new-song-fellowship/id415636728?mt=2&uo=4",
      "feedUrl": "http://lily.nowsprouting.com/newsongfellowship/podcast.php?pageID=10",
      "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/in/podcast/new-song-fellowship/id415636728?mt=2&uo=4",
      "artworkUrl30": "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music62/v4/34/b0/16/34b016de-a98f-0bc2-38ca-45ed2f22fe65/source/30x30bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl60": "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music62/v4/34/b0/16/34b016de-a98f-0bc2-38ca-45ed2f22fe65/source/60x60bb.jpg",
      "artworkUrl100": "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music62/v4/34/b0/16/34b016de-a98f-0bc2-38ca-45ed2f22fe65/source/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 0,
      "trackPrice": 0,
      "trackRentalPrice": 0,
      "collectionHdPrice": 0,
      "trackHdPrice": 0,
      "trackHdRentalPrice": 0,
      "releaseDate": "2015-12-04T18:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "cleaned",
      "trackExplicitness": "cleaned",
      "trackCount": 30,
      "country": "IND",
      "currency": "INR",
      "primaryGenreName": "Christianity",
      "contentAdvisoryRating": "Clean",
      "artworkUrl600": "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music62/v4/34/b0/16/34b016de-a98f-0bc2-38ca-45ed2f22fe65/source/600x600bb.jpg",
      "genreIds": [
        "1439",
        "26",
        "1314"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "Christianity",
        "Podcasts",
        "Religion & Spirituality"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*As far as I know* doesn't iTunes store the podcasts themselve. 
Instead the podcasters are providing (mostly rss-feeds) that contain **XML** , which contains links to the episode files of the podcast.

The feed is the value for "feedUrl"  in your response.

```
"feedUrl": "http://lily.nowsprouting.com/newsongfellowship/podcast.php?pageID=10"
```

Those feeds look similar to this form:

- a "header" with xml version, unicode and the itunes dtd
- channel -
- fu
  ...

  and then a (literally its name) item for every podcast that is available in the feed in the form of:

[image: this is from the podcast you mentioned, url to mp3 highlighted]

if you want to parse that, you want to read into XMLParser ;-)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmlparser